# UIButton on UIView inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have a UIScrollView (similar to that seen showing the featured items on the App Store) which has 3 views, with xibs, loaded into it.  Everything works find except I can get the UIButtons which I have on the xibs to fire.  I guess I am missing something obvious just can't see it.  I've tried various answers on here and other places to no avail.

Thanks in advance

Code from viewDidLoad on ViewController containing scroll view

```
LSCWInfoView *view1 = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                         loadNibNamed:@"LSCW-InfoView"
                         owner:self options:nil]
                        firstObject];

CGRect frame;
frame.origin.x = 0;
frame.origin.y = 0;
frame.size = self.activityPageControl.frame.size;

[view1 setFrame:frame];

[self.activityScrollView addSubview:view1];

ScrambledInfoView *view2 = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                             loadNibNamed:@"Scrambled-InfoView"
                             owner:self options:nil]
                            firstObject];

CGRect frame2;
frame2.origin.x = 320;
frame2.origin.y = 0;
frame2.size = self.activityPageControl.frame.size;

[view2 setFrame:frame2];

[self.activityScrollView addSubview:view2];


TestInfoView *view3 = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                         loadNibNamed:@"Test-InfoView"
                         owner:self options:nil]
                        firstObject];

CGRect frame3;
frame3.origin.x = 640;
frame3.origin.y = 0;
frame3.size = self.activityPageControl.frame.size;

[view3 setFrame:frame3];

[self.activityScrollView addSubview:view3];

_activityScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_activityScrollView.frame.size.width * 3, _activityScrollView.frame.size.height);
```

EDIT - Code for one of the views loaded into the scroll view (other 2 are the same)

```
#import "LSCWInfoView.h"

@implementation LSCWInfoView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

- (IBAction)lscwPlayButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"YEP");
}

@end
```

Screenshots
[image: Showing view controller w/ scrollview]

[image: Showing view which is loaded into scrollview]

Comment: did u assigned any outlet for action to the acutal view

Comment: Yeah I have a IBActions on the views that are loaded into the scroll view.  Not working at present.

Comment: What about ur view code. its not available above try to post the code involved in view.

Comment: I think something wrong with the ur xib file. If possible u may share u project here or else check whether u connected the outlet properly.

Comment: Where are the buttons ? They need to be in the LCSWInfoView for that IBAction to trigger / be linked.

Comment: The buttons are on LCSWInfoView's xib file and are properly linked with IBActions in the view subclass.  It seems like the scrollview is preventing the touch from getting down to the button, as the colour of the button doesn't change and the IBAction isn't fired.

Comment: Copy and past the view hierarchy from the controller (bit on the left which shows all the elements you have in the controller).

Comment: View hierarchy on view controller containing scrollview - View, Page Control, Scroll View

Comment: View hierarchy on view (loaded into scrollview) - View, Label, Button, Label, ImageView

Comment: We need the visuals of how you have wired this up to solve it. Do screen grabs of the view heirarchy and also of the IBOutlet connections by right clicking on the view controller. E.g http://www.techotopia.com/images/f/f6/Iphone_ios6_document_outline_constraints.png

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45386/discussion-between-ohnomycoco-and-nicktones)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by setting the frame size of the view before it is added to the scrollview